# Why does Axios keep sending requests before component mounts?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

I have an app with React front and Spring backend. I use Axios to fetch from the back. I have 2 class components with tables and I can access them via a menu component (in componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate only). I use all the possible precautions against infinite loops (loaded state and isMounted with a custom name). It works in the first component which I access after logging in. However, the second component (which is logically the same as the first, just has another entity to fetch) keeps requesting with axios until i go there (i see it in the network tab of my browser). Why can it be? it is definitely not mounted and console.logs don't work from there but while I'm on first it keeps requesting on and on (and it doesn't receive anything I guess, it is 0 bytes at this time)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios'
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import {Button, ButtonToolbar} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import AddCalculationsModal from './AddCalculationsModal';
import UpdateCalculationsModal from './UpdateCalculationsModal';
import Cluster from './Cluster';
import Select from 'react-select/src/Select';

export default class Calculations extends Component {
  isCMounted = false;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        items: [],
        selected: null,
        addModalShow: false,
        updateModalShow: false,
        updateId: null,
        buttonOn: false,
        page: 0,
        elements: 0,
        loaded: false
    }
}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.isCMounted = true;
    if(!this.state.loaded){
      this.load();
    }
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if(!this.state.loaded){
      this.load();
    }
  };

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.isCMounted = false;
  }

  increasePage = () => {
    this.setState({
      page: this.state.page + 1
    })
  }

  decreasePage = () => {
    this.setState({
      page: this.state.page - 1
    })
  }

  load = async () => {
    await axios.get(`calculations?page=${this.state.page}&elements=${this.state.elements}`)
    .then(res => {
      if (this.isCMounted && this.state.items.id === res.data.id){
        this.setState({items: res.data})
      }
    });
    if(this.state.selected != null && this.isCMounted) {
      this.setState({buttonOn: true})
    }
    this.setState({loaded: true})
  }

  setId = (id) => {
    const idValue = this.state.items[id].id;
    if (this.isCMounted)
      this.setState({updateId: idValue});
  }

  deleteRow = (id) => {
    const index = this.state.items.findIndex(item => {
      return item.id === this.state.items[id].id})
      const idValue = this.state.items[id].id

    axios.delete(`calculations/${idValue}`).then(
      res => {
        this.load();
      }
    )

    this.state.items.splice(index, 1)
    this.load();
  }

  render() {
    let addModalClose = () => this.setState({addModalShow: false});
    let updateModalClose = () => this.setState({updateModalShow: false});
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Calculations</h3>
        <ReactTable
          columns={
            [
              {
                Header: "ID",
                accessor: "id"
              },
              {
                Header: "Name",
                accessor: "name"
              },
              {
                Header: "Creation Date",
                accessor: "dateCreate"
              },
              {
                Header: "Update Date",
                accessor: "dateUpdate"
              },
              {
                Header: "User",
                accessor: "userId"
              }
            ]  
          }
          data={this.state.items}
          filterable
          showPagination={false}
          getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
            if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
              return {
                onClick: (e) => {
                  this.setState({
                    selected: rowInfo.index
                  })
                },
                style: {
                  background: rowInfo.index === this.state.selected ? '#00afec' : 'white',
                  color: rowInfo.index === this.state.selected ? 'white' : 'black'
                }
              }
            }else{
              return {}
            }
          }}
          >
      </ReactTable>
      <ButtonToolbar>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => {
          this.decreasePage();
          this.load();
        }}>PREVIOUS PAGE</Button>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => {
        this.increasePage();
        this.load();
      }}>NEXT PAGE</Button>
      </ButtonToolbar>
      <ButtonToolbar>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.setState({addModalShow: true})}>
          Add Calculation
        </Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => {
          this.setId(this.state.selected);
          this.setState({updateModalShow: true})}} disabled={this.state.buttonOn ? false : true}>
          Update Calculation
        </Button>
        <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => {
          this.deleteRow(this.state.selected);
        }}>DELETE</Button>

        <Link to={`/calculations/${this.state.items[this.state.selected] && this.state.items[this.state.selected].id}`}>
          <Button variant="warning" disabled={this.state.buttonOn ? false : true}>Cluster</Button>
        </Link>

        <AddCalculationsModal 
          show={this.state.addModalShow}
          onHide={addModalClose}
          calculation={this.state.items[this.state.selected]}
          />

        <UpdateCalculationsModal 
          show={this.state.updateModalShow}
          onHide={updateModalClose}
          calculation={this.state.items[this.state.selected] && this.state.items[this.state.selected].id}
          calcname={this.state.items[this.state.selected] && this.state.items[this.state.selected].name}
          />

      </ButtonToolbar>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import {Button, ButtonToolbar} from 'react-bootstrap';
import AuthenticationService from '../service/AuthenticationService';

export default class Calculations extends Component {
  isCMounted = false;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        items: [],
        selected: null,
        updateId: null,
        loaded: false
    }
}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.isCMounted = true;
    if(!this.state.loaded) {
      this.load();
    }
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if(!this.state.loaded) {
      this.load();
    }
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.isCMounted = false;
  }

  load = async () => {
    if(this.isCMounted && !this.state.loaded) {
    await axios.get('calculation-types')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(this.isCMounted)
      if (this.isCMounted && this.state.items.id === res.data.id){
      this.setState({items: res.data})
      }
    });
  this.setState({loaded: true})
  }
  }

  setId = (id) => {
    const idValue = this.state.items[id].id;
    if (this.isCMounted)
    this.setState({updateId: idValue});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Calculation Types</h3>
        <ReactTable
          columns={
            [
              {
                Header: "ID",
                accessor: "idType",
                width: 100,
                minWidth: 100,
                maxWidth: 100          
              },
              {
                Header: "Name",
                accessor: "name"
              }
            ]  
          }
          data={this.state.items}
          filterable
          showPagination={false}
          getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
            if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
              return {
                onClick: (e) => {
                  this.setState({
                    selected: rowInfo.index
                  })
                },
                style: {
                  background: rowInfo.index === this.state.selected ? '#00afec' : 'white',
                  color: rowInfo.index === this.state.selected ? 'white' : 'black'
                }
              }
            }else{
              return {}
            }
          }}
          >
      </ReactTable>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

are my components. Menu is a normal link. after login i appear on the first with menu on top.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, otherwise, we can't really help.

Comment: Define "definitely not mounted".

Comment: Edited now, but files are big...

Comment: That's why @EmileBergeron mentioned [mre] (note the "minimal", meaning "just enough to reproduce the error, not the entire application").

Comment: What's the rational for believing it's not mounted?

Comment: I don't know how much is enough. I don't even know why it happens so I don't know where the mistake might be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried moving `this.setState({loaded: true})` into the axios response callback block? Since you're awaiting the fetch request, I wonder if the `this.setState({items: res.data}` that you have in the callback block is causing an infinite `componentDidUpdate` loop that causes `load` to be repeatedly called without ever having the chance to arrive at the `this.setState({loaded: true})` in the final line of `load`.

```
load = async () => {
  if(this.isCMounted && !this.state.loaded) {
    await axios.get('calculation-types')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(this.isCMounted)
        if (this.isCMounted && this.state.items.id === res.data.id){
          this.setState({ items: res.data, loaded: true })
        }
      });
  }
}
```